# Not able to access image hosted in Apache server using Java code

Tags: java, jsp

My java code is like this.

```
String imgSrc= GlobalConstants.CDN_SERVER+ "/images/generic_image.gif";                     
BufferedImage originalImage=ImageIO.read(new File(imgSrc));
ByteArrayOutputStream baos=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ImageIO.write(originalImage, "jpg", baos );
byte[] imageInByte=baos.toByteArray();
```

I have hosted my files in **Apache HTTP server**.

**GlobalConstants.CDN_SERVER** is `"http://localhost/abc"`

I am trying to access **generic_image.gif** from the Apache sever, but it‘s throwing this error for second line of code.i.e. `BufferedImage originalImage=ImageIO.read(new File(imgSrc))`

```
javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!
javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
```

But if I am trying to access same image from jsp it's working fine. i.e.

```
<src="<%=GlobalConstants.CDN_SERVER%>/images/generic_image.gif"/>
```

Am I doing something wrong ? Guide me thanks .

Comment: Thanks @Sotirios Delimanolis for editing my code.

Comment: Are URLs like `http://localhost/abc/images/generic_image.gif` served by the same http server?

Comment: yes absolutely right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try following code

```
URL url = new URL(GlobalConstants.CDN_SERVER+ "/images/generic_image.gif");
BufferedImage originalImage = ImageIO.read(url);
```

Comment: Can you explain me whats wrong in my code and why it is not working ? @sasankad

Comment: @Sthita, A File object represents a file on the computer where the code is running. So images/Files on other computers hosted through web can't be represented by a File object starting from http://